# iOS Parse verify that anonymous user has signed up

Tags: ios, objective-c, parsing, keychain

I want to convert an anonymous user to a regular user without the actual user being aware of the sign up procedure.

Here's what I'm trying to achieve: Our app should be usable without signing up for the service. In order to still provide user specific content synchronized with the Parse Server, an user account is unavoidable. In order to implement this my plan is to create an anonymous user (see Parse [docs](https://parseplatform.github.io/docs/ios/guide/#anonymous-users)) and then convert the anonymous user into a regular user with an auto generated password. The credentials are then stored into the Keychain, so the user can close the app and even reinstall it without losing the credentials and thus access data.

Every time the app is started, I check if the Keychain has valid credentials and if not it creates a new anonymous user.

So far so good, but I ran into the question of how to check if the user actually is an anonymous user or if the account has already been converted into a real account. I'm aware of the `PFAnonymousUtils` and in particular:

```
if ([PFAnonymousUtils isLinkedWithUser:[PFUser currentUser]]) {

}
```

Nevertheless the following scenario makes the function useless.

1. I create an anonymous user and proceed without converting it into an regular user (Not setting username & password yet)
2. I create an Object and save it to the Parse backend
3. I store the Object and by doing so the user will be signed up, as storing an Object will convert an anonymous user into a regular user
4. How do I check now if the user is anonymous and if I still have to auto generate a password an store it?

What's best practice here, any suggestions are appreciated! Maybe there's even an easier way to do this.

Comment: I have worked with the parse and i am totally aware of it, but i am not getting what you are trying to do, so it would be help if you can describe that what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: @SatishMavani Any PFObject I have belongs to a PFUser. I don't want to require users to sign up for our service, with an email, username and password, but the creator should still be the only being able to modify the data. My idea is to create a user account with random autogenerated credentials save them to the keychain and use them to authenticate the user.

Comment: I am not aware about keychain thing but as per my understanding if you have saved user when app launches, then you should log in your user in background with username and password.

Let me know if i am not getting anythin here.

Comment: @SatishMavani Let me maybe ask a simpler question, if I enable ```enableAutomaticUser```  then ```isLinkedWithUser``` always returns YES, even if the userId is nil and the user is not yet saved to Parse.

Comment: Let me maybe ask a simpler question, if I enable enableAutomaticUser then isLinkedWithUser always returns YES, even if the userId is nil and the user is not yet saved to Parse.

sorry but what is the question here?

Comment: That's not expected behavior in my opinion, how am I supposed to check then if the user is indeed associated with a parse object. I thought that was the purpose of ```isLinkedWithUser```

Comment: Can you try this:

if([[PFUser currentUser]isLinkedWithAuthType:@"anonymous"]){
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124435/discussion-between-kevin-goedecke-and-satish-mavani).